Explicit description of cohomology functor image of function
Let $X$ be a scheme over an affine base Spec(A), $a$ be regular element of A and $\mathcal{F}$ a quasi-coherent functor that is flat over A. I've built a short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F/aF}  \rightarrow 0$$
I want to show that there is a short exact sequence:
$$0 \rightarrow H^p(X, \mathcal{F})/aH^p(X, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^p(X, \mathcal{F/aF})\rightarrow H^{p+1}(X, \mathcal{F})[a]\rightarrow 0$$
with $M[a] = \{m \in M, am =0\}$.
I start from the initial short exact sequence and get a long exact cohomology sequence. I can then split it into a short exact sequence at each power $p$ that looks like this:
$$0 \rightarrow coker \rightarrow H^p(X, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow im \rightarrow 0$$
where I suppose that coker and im are what I want. Thought it may be evident, I struggle to understand how the cohomology functors act on morphisms and how the coboundary acts explicitly. Could someone please guide me through?

Consider the following chain in the long exact sequence in cohomology:
$$H^p(X, \mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{a} H^p(X,\mathscr{F}) \to H^p(X, \mathscr{F}/a\mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^{p+1}(X, \mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{a} H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})$$
The cokernel of the first map is (isomorphic to) the image of the second map, so we obtain an exact sequence $$0\to \frac{H^p(X,\mathscr{F})}{aH^p(X,\mathscr{F})} \to H^p(X,\mathscr{F}/a\mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{a} H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})$$ Finally, observe the image of the coboundary map $\delta$ is $\ker(H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{a} H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})) = H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})[a]$. This yields a further splitting into exact sequences $0 \to H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})[a] \to H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F}) \xrightarrow{a} H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})$ and $$0\to \frac{H^p(X,\mathscr{F})}{aH^p(X,\mathscr{F})} \to H^p(X,\mathscr{F}/a\mathscr{F}) \to H^{p+1}(X,\mathscr{F})[a]\to 0$$
